# ContentEditable HTML5 localStorage sometimes not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I tried to use "ContentEditable" from this Demo for 3 divs of my site:

http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

I also load the h5utils.js from this demo for the event listener

For example, one of the divs looks like this:

```
<div class="statsWrapper">
    <header id="met30" contenteditable="true" class="Tester">
</header>
    <p class="statsmonth_tester">
       Tester Overall
    </p>
</div>
```

My Script in the html

```
        <script>
        //Script for saving Content Sales Report to local storage//

        var editableTester = document.getElementById('met30');
        var editableSubscriber = document.getElementById('met32');
        var editableReadOnly = document.getElementById('met35');

        addEvent(editableTester, 'blur', function() {
            localStorage.setItem('Tester', this.innerHTML);
            document.designMode = 'off';                
        });

        addEvent(editableSubscriber, 'blur', function() {
            localStorage.setItem('Subscriber', this.innerHTML);
            document.designMode = 'off';
        });

        addEvent(editableReadOnly, 'blur', function() {
            localStorage.setItem('ReadOnly', this.innerHTML);
            document.designMode = 'off';
        });

        addEvent(editableTester, 'focus', function() {
            document.designMode = 'on';
        });
        addEvent(editableSubscriber, 'focus', function() {
            document.designMode = 'on';
        });
        addEvent(editableReadOnly, 'focus', function() {
            document.designMode = 'on';
        });

        if (localStorage.getItem('Tester')) {
            editableTester.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('Tester');
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem('Subscriber')) {
            editableSubscriber.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('Subscriber');
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem('ReadOnly')) {
            editableReadOnly.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('ReadOnly');
        }               
    </script>
```

The Problem is:

I´m always able to edit the divs
But sometimes the localStorage will not updated with the new values of my divs after edit them. 
After reload the window, all values are the old one. But it's strange: Sometimes It works, If I open the code in new window. Any ideas? (sorry for my english)

Comment: Remove capital letters from your localstorage keys.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the script after the DOM is fully loaded? many ways to achieve that. but the easiest is probably using jQuery `(document).ready(//here comes your code)`

Comment: I have removed capital letters an I run the script after the DOM is fully loaded. But no changes

Comment: I can reproduce the problem: If I use the backspace-key to delete some content, the localstorage will not be updated (11, del1 -> 1: localstorage: 11). If i change the content, for e.g. 11, del1 and add 2 -> 12: localstorage: 12). That seems a bug?!

Comment: @user1735856 maybe I'm missing the bug here, I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alonisser/udL36/1/) with your script where everything seems to work right

Comment: @user1735856 you should notice that you are listening here to 'focus' and 'blur' events. so localstorage would be updated only after moving the focus out of the div. if you want localstorage to update immediatly after using backspace you should listen to 'keydown' or 'keypress' (something like that) and check if the key is backspace or enter and update accordingly